# SPListItem.Properties DateTime Fields are in weird Hex format

Tags: sharepoint

Does anyone know how to convert these string hex values back into DateTime values?

Property my_DateProperty (System.String) = 0x01c9874e|0x98f28800

```
//l_item is SPListItem          
Hashtable l_properties = l_item.Properties;
if (l_properties != null)
{
    object l_value = null;
    foreach (string l_key in l_properties.Keys)
    {
        l_value = l_properties[l_key];
        Splogger.log("Property " + l_key + " (" + l_value.GetType().ToString() + ") = " + l_value.ToString());
    }
}
```

Comment: I've noticed this too, it only seems to be the case when you are accessng properties through the HashTable, not directly from the list item.  

I think this has to do with the way the HashTable class stores data.

Comment: Also see this question http://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/66602/dates-and-times-in-properties-vs-fields/91069#91069

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I discovered recently that this seems to occur only on Office 2007 documents (for other file types, the value is a standard string format for a date).  The answer is that the hexadecimal value represents the number of ticks since the 1/1/1600.  Here is a conversion that worked for me:

Dim dateVal as DateTime = New DateTime(Long.Parse(dateText.Replace("0x", "").Replace("|", ""), System.Globalization.NumberStyles.HexNumber)).AddYears(1600)

Comment: Did you determine why this happens only to Office 2007 documents? That is a really oddball case to take care of, considering that document libraries are supposed to support many file types with the expectation of a consistent behavior. I have been grappling with this issue and almost concluded that the item was corrupted. Glad I came across this post!

Answer (score 0):

Could be you that the datetime is being converted into an "invariant" date by the ToString. [See this](http://weblogs.asp.net/gunnarpeipman/archive/2008/05/14/sharepoint-assigning-values-to-datetime-fields.aspx).