# DateTime Hex Format

Tags: sharepoint, datetime

I'm getting a hex string when converting a SPListItem's date.

eg. "0x01c9d2be|0x809a8800"

[This question answers it.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/521078/splistitem-properties-datetime-fields-are-in-weird-hex-format)

However, what's the proper way to convert it, what format is the DateTime object in?
What if I want to set the datetime? Would I have to convert it into hex format and assign it as a hex string?

There has to be a better and ideal way to extract modify the DateTime object.

Any ideas?

Thanks.

Comment: The upvoted answer to the linked question answers everything as far as I can tell.

Comment: How would you be able to create the hex?

Comment: can't you just case the field value as a date time? and just set the field value to a date time too.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm able to extract the date and time. That's fine.

So when you are modifying the DateTime of a ListItem, you just simply assign it as a DateTime format and it will interpret it correctly; no need to generate the hex that it returns.

Answer (score 2):

A DateTime value in .NET can also be represented as a 64-bit value. The strange string format on DateTime fields on SharePoint list items is a variant of such a 64-bit value encoded as two 32-bit hex values. I have found no documentation from Microsoft on this format. But by trial and error I found the following conversion method:

```
string[] words = strVal.Split('|');
int high = int.Parse(words[0].Substring(2), System.Globalization.NumberStyles.HexNumber);
uint low = uint.Parse(words[1].Substring(2), System.Globalization.NumberStyles.HexNumber);
long ticks = high;
ticks = ticks << 32;
ticks += low;
DateTime t = new DateTime(ticks);
t = t.AddYears(1600);
```

where t holds the result.

Answer (score 1):

Another solution can be found here. It has something to do how Office 2007 stores dates..
[SPListItem.Properties DateTime Fields are in weird Hex format](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/521078/splistitem-properties-datetime-fields-are-in-weird-hex-format)